# What is the coordinate of the maximum value of a quadratic function given by two points and axis?

Tags: functions, optimization, quadratics

There are only three pieces of information available:

> 1. the graph passes through (0,0) and (6,0)
> 2. the symmetry axis is $x$ = 3
> 3. the graph is downward

My attempt:

I've tried to work on that problem and got quadratic function $y = ax^2 - 6ax$. However, I couldn't find the value of $a$ and of course the coordinate of the maximum value.

Comment: If you know it's a quadratic, then the first bit of information implies the second.

Comment: @ZainPatel, sorry, I forgot the third information

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic functions which vanish at $x=0$ and $x=6$ are one-parameter family, and their equation, as you found it, is: 
$$y=ax(x-6).$$
There's a maximum only if $a<0$. If $a>0$, the function has a *minimum*. In any case the extremum is obtained at the midsum of the roots, i.e. at $x=3$. Hence the maximum, if $a<0$, is
$$y(3)=-9a.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since it is quadratic then you can represent it as 
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 0
$$
and this must be true for both of your data points, i.e., 
$$
0 = a(0)^2 + b(0) + c
$$
and
$$
0 = a(6)^2+ b(6) + c
$$
The first data point's equation leads to $c=0$.  Then the second gives
$
36a + 6b = 0
$ or $6a+b=0$.  Substituting $b=-6a$ gives you your equation
$$
y = ax^2-6ax
$$

With what's given, there isn't sufficient information to find a single value of $a$ that will give the minimum (it is $-9a$).  If you had another data point it would give enough for a unique solution.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/da1iddugam

[image]

Comment: You've over-complicated it a bit, you know the roots are $0$ and $6$ so the quadratic is $ax(x-6)$.

Comment: @ZainPatel yes maybe, but I don't think everyone knows to "jump" to the form $ax(x-6)$ when the roots are $0$ and $6$.  I've just shown how to get there with the given information.